# 2 Docker environments in same VPC

Tags: networking, docker, docker-swarm, consul

I am trying to contain my dev & qa environment in same vpc. I have created separate overlay networks named:

- qa
- dev

My dev env is up and running smoothly. I am using same container names for qa env also.

When I try to register my container to swarm it is complaining this:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict: The name mongo2 is already assigned. You have to delete (or rename) that container to be able to assign mongo2 to a container again..
```

What should I do in this case.

**Note:** docker0 of both environments on which swarm manger is running have same subnet mask.

Comment: Can't you just rename the container.

Comment: @tlenss I have around 20-25 containers. Renaming is the last option I wan't to go with.

Comment: Docker container names must be unique. Like a unique key in a db table. You could register your new qa environments with _qa extensions for the new containers? Otherwise, it wouldn't know the difference between your containers being in dev or qa when linking dependent containers for example or start/stop commands and etc. Or am I missing something in your question?

Comment: @TimCederquist I did the same what you are suggesting. But now I am not able to connect from one docker container to another. I am getting "No route to host". However docker discovery is working fine. Only issue is when we try to ping other container. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using --link or -p with open ports to connect the services between containers? If link it should work by name/port using your new alias (which needs to be unique to a container in the swarm as well). However, if by port you'll probably have challenges knowing which server is hosting the container so i'd look at switching to --link. Here is a link with a sample of two containers and how you would ping container 1 from container 2 through the link: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/#linking-containers-in-user-defined-networks.

Comment: If you update the question to include the networking issue, I'd be happy to write up the detail for others that may encounter the same challenge if this is helping you out.

Comment: regarding the networking issue, you can also use the net-alias as described there: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/